# php - echo require code passed in variable

Tags: php, echo, require

I have some sudo code here

```
    $image_position = left

    switch($image_position){
        case 'left':
            $block_con = "require(locate_template('templates/block-media-left.php'))";
            break;
        case 'right':
            $block_con = 'require(locate_template("templates/block-media-right.php"))';
            break;
        case 'center':
            $block_con = 'require(locate_template("templates/block-media-center.php"))';
            break;  
        default:
            $block_con = 'require(locate_template("templates/block-text.php"))';

    }


    <div>

        <?php echo $block_con; ?>

    </div>
```

Depending on the value of the $image_position I want to load a different block of php found in a templates folder.

The switch works but echo a string and does not add the require code.

I didn't think it would but don't know how to do this.

Comment: Why don t you just execute the require when you pass in the switch? And put the switch inside your div.

Comment: I think you need eval() but some guys say that it's evil.

Comment: Also your php balises around the switch are lacking, i doubt this code execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
<?php 
$image_position = 'left';
switch($image_position){
    case 'left':
        $block_con = 'templates/block-media-left.php';
        break;
    case 'right':
        $block_con = 'templates/block-media-right.php';
        break;
    case 'center':
        $block_con = 'templates/block-media-center.php';
        break;  
    default:
        $block_con = 'templates/block-text.php';
}
?>


<div>
    <?php require(locate_template($block_con)); ?>
</div>
```

It's important to note that this is just REQUIRING the PHP file currently. This means it'll be included and executed. You'd have to echo in that included PHP file to get any output.

Comment: Still lacking php balises on the switch but yeah this one should work if you add them.

Comment: @LaurentFauvel Updated, thanks. That's what I get for copypasta :)

Comment: What in the world are _php balises_?

Comment: @AbraCadaver <?php and ?> http://php.net/manual/fr/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: Sorry it's just sudo code, I have tags in the actual code

Comment: Hey @ttmt, Did this work for ya? Need any further assistance?